# Parsing JSON in PLSQL

Tags: json, oracle, rest, plsql

I have a following code in a PLSQL Proc.

```
Declare

 url VARCHAR2(1000) := p_url;
    l_json     json_object_t := json_object_t();
    l_children json_array_t  := json_array_t();
    envelope CLOB;
    response_text CLOB;

    CURSOR getHdrRec IS
        SELECT hdr.bill_to_account_id,
               hdr.bill_to_account_name,
               hdr.bill_to_party_number,
               hdr.bill_to_party_site_number,
               hdr.vat_code,
               hdr.vat_code_description,
               hdr.vat_code_value,
               hdr.due_date,
               hdr.due_date2,
               hdr.due_date3,
               hdr.company_id,
               hdr.depot_id,
               hdr.document_id,
               hdr.trx_date,
               hdr.project_id,
               hdr.ship_to_account_id,
               hdr.ship_to_party_site_number,
               sysdate creation_date
        FROM xxrr_billing_invoice_hdr_stg hdr
        WHERE hdr.record_status = 'N';


    CURSOR getLnRec (c_document_id in VARCHAR2) IS
         SELECT ln.line_id,
                ln.document_id,
                ln.item_code,
                ln.item_definition_code,
                ln.item_description,
                ln.quantity,
                ln.hire_period3,
                ln.line_value
         FROM xxrr_billing_invoice_line_stg ln
         WHERE ln.document_id = c_document_id
           AND ln.record_status = 'N';  

BEGIN

       FOR i IN getHdrRec LOOP
        -- Create JSON payload
        l_json.put('BillToCustomerNumber',i.bill_to_account_id);
        l_json.put('BillToCustomerName',i.bill_to_account_name);
        l_json.put('BillToSite',i.bill_to_party_site_number);
        l_json.put('DueDate',i.due_date);
        l_json.put('BusinessUnit',i.company_id);
        l_json.put('CrossReference',i.document_id);
        l_json.put('TransactionDate',i.trx_date);
        l_json.put('CreationDate',i.creation_date);
        l_json.put('ShipToCustomerNumber',i.ship_to_account_id);
        l_json.put('ShipToSite',i.ship_to_party_site_number);
        l_json.put('TransactionSource','Equipment Rental');
        l_json.put('TransactionType','Invoice');
        l_json.put('InvoiceCurrencyCode','USD');

          FOR j IN getlnrec (i.document_id) LOOP

             l_children.append(json_object_t('{"LineNumber":"'|| j.line_id || '"}'));
             l_children.append(json_object_t('{"ItemNumber":"'||j.item_code||'"}'));
             l_children.append(json_object_t('{"Description":"'||j.item_description||'"}'));
             l_children.append(json_object_t('{"Quantity":"'||j.Quantity||'"}'));
             l_children.append(json_object_t('{"UnitSellingPrice":"'||j.line_value||'"}'));
             
          END LOOP;

          l_json.put('receivablesInvoiceLines',l_children);
        END LOOP;

        envelope := l_json.to_clob;
       

        dbms_output.put_line('clob:'||envelope);

     /*   Select request_fusion(
            p_path =>  '/',
            g_fusion_url => p_url,
            p_method => 'POST',
            g_fusion_cred => 'FSCM_API',
            p_body => envelope
            ) into P_response from Dual;*/
     dbms_output.put_line('P_RESPONSE clob:'||p_response);

END;
```

This code generates following JSON.

```
"{
  "BillToCustomerNumber" : "29292",
  "BillToCustomerName" : "ABCD Corp",
  "BillToSite" : "136036",
  "DueDate" : "2023-07-31T00:00:00",
  "BusinessUnit" : "XYZ Corp",
  "CrossReference" : 56565656,
  "TransactionDate" : null,
  "CreationDate" : "2023-08-22T20:22:43",
  "ShipToCustomerNumber" : "29292",
  "ShipToSite" : "136037",
  "TransactionSource" : "Equipment Rental",
  "TransactionType" : "Invoice",
  "InvoiceCurrencyCode" : "USD",
  "receivablesInvoiceLines" :
  [
    {
      "LineNumber" : "1"
    },
    {
      "ItemNumber" : "103629"
    },
    {
      "Description" : "TEST DESCRIPTION1"
    }
  ]
}"
```

The the way receivablesInvoiceLines children are generated in above JSON is creating errors.  My expectation is that following is how the JSON should generate.

```
{
  "BillToCustomerNumber" : "29292",
  "BillToCustomerName" : "ABCD Corp",
  "BillToSite" : "59329",
  "DueDate" : "2023-07-31T00:00:00",
  "BusinessUnit" : "XYZ Corp",
  "CrossReference" : "56565656",
  "TransactionDate" : "2023-07-07",
  "ShipToSite" : "136037",
  "TransactionSource" : "Equipment Rental",
  "TransactionType" : "Invoice",
  "InvoiceCurrencyCode" : "USD",
  "receivablesInvoiceLines" :
  [
    {
      "LineNumber" : "1",
      "ItemNumber" : "103629",
      "Description" : "TEST DESCRIPTION1",
      "Quantity" : 10,
      "UnitSellingPrice" : 1100
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I fix my code under l_children.append to generate JSON correctly?

Thank you,
Darsh

Comment: Btw,  would you be able to tell me how to solve the issue above?

Comment: I think you need to replace your loop with something like `FOR j IN getlnrec (i.document_id) LOOP l_child := json_object_t(); l_child.put('LineNumber', j.line_id); -- other puts; l_children.append(l_child); END LOOP;`

Comment: You'll need to declare `l_child` at the beginning too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a similar example based on the emp/dept sample dataset. The issue you have is that you have declared l_children as data type json_array_t, but you don't want it to be an array of elements, you want it to be an array of json objects.

What you have is similar to this (just printing the first line of output):

```
DECLARE 
    l_json     json_object_t := json_object_t();
    l_children json_array_t  := json_array_t();
    CURSOR c_dept IS
      SELECT dname, deptno FROM dept;
    CURSOR c_emp (deptno_i IN number) IS
      SELECT ename, job FROM emp WHERE deptno = deptno_i;
BEGIN
   FOR i IN c_dept LOOP
   -- Create JSON payload
      l_json.put('dname',i.dname);
      FOR j IN c_emp (i.deptno) LOOP
      
        l_children.append(json_object_t('{"ename":"'|| j.ename || '"}'));
        l_children.append(json_object_t('{"job":"'|| j.job || '"}'));
      END LOOP;
      l_json.put('employees',l_children);
      dbms_output.put_line(l_json.to_clob);
   END LOOP;
END;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

{
  "dname": "ACCOUNTING",
  "employees": [
    {
      "ename": "KING"
    },
    {
      "job": "PRESIDENT"
    },
    {
      "ename": "CLARK"
    },
    {
      "job": "MANAGER"
    },
    {
      "ename": "MILLER"
    },
    {
      "job": "CLERK"
    }
  ]
}
```

It is working as expected. Children is defined as an array but... you want the object inside the array. So add the elements to the object, then add the object to the array:

```
DECLARE 
    l_json     json_object_t := json_object_t();
    l_children json_object_t  := json_object_t();
    l_children_arr json_array_t  := json_array_t();
    CURSOR c_dept IS
      SELECT dname, deptno FROM dept;
    CURSOR c_emp (deptno_i IN number) IS
      SELECT ename, job FROM emp WHERE deptno = deptno_i;
BEGIN
   FOR i IN c_dept LOOP
   -- Create JSON payload
      l_json.put('dname',i.dname);
      FOR j IN c_emp (i.deptno) LOOP
        l_children.put('ename',j.ename);
        l_children.put('job',j.job);
      END LOOP;
      l_children_arr.append(l_children);
      l_json.put('employees',l_children_arr);
      dbms_output.put_line(l_json.to_clob);
   END LOOP;
END;
/

{
  "dname": "ACCOUNTING",
  "employees": [
    {
      "ename": "KING",
      "job": "PRESIDENT"
    },
    {
      "ename": "CLARK",
      "job": "MANAGER"
    },
    {
      "ename": "MILLER",
      "job": "CLERK"
    }
  ]
}
```