# Generating deep nested JSON palyload out of Oracle SQL

Tags: json, oracle, rest, plsql, oracle-apex

I have a need to generate a three level nested JSON payload out of Oracle tables.  I have described two approaches I have used to accomplish this and neither of them work.   Please advise where am I going wrong!

**Approach 1**

Following select is supposed to generate a single json clob containing header, line and detail line tables. You will see that I am trying to get header, lines and distribution lines payload but its not working.  I am getting header rows repeating with every line rows. So, as a result when this payload goes into a webservice, because header row is repeating, webservice will throw an error.   How can I make header row not repeat with every line row?

```
select json_object
(
KEY 'InvoiceNumber'   VALUE  h.document_id,
KEY 'InvoiceCurrency' VALUE  'USD',
KEY 'InvoiceAmount'   VALUE  h.amount,
KEY 'InvoiceDate'     VALUE  h.trx_date,
KEY 'BusinessUnit'    VALUE  'ABCD Corp',
KEY 'Supplier'        VALUE  'NASA',
KEY 'SupplierSite'    VALUE  'PHYSICAL',
KEY 'InvoiceGroup'    VALUE  'MoonLander',
KEY 'Description'     VALUE  'Some Description',
KEY 'invoiceLines' VALUE  json_array
       (
        json_object 
           ( KEY 'LineNumber' VALUE t.line_id,
             KEY 'LineAmount' VALUE t.line_Value,
             KEY 'invoiceDistributions' VALUE json_array 
            (
              json_object 
              (
               KEY 'DistributionLineNumber' VALUE t.line_id,
               KEY 'DistributionLineType'   VALUE 'Item',
               KEY 'DistributionAmount'     VALUE  t.line_Value
              )
            )
            ))FORMAT JSON
    )JSON_VALUE
INTO aCLOB
from XXRR_HDR_STG h,
     XXRR_LINE_STG t
where t.document_id = h.document_id
and  h.document_id = 543210
order by t.line_id;
```

**Approach 2**

This approach uses Json Object and arrays.  This is my preferable option but this gives Json Syntax error during runtime.

```
  FOR i IN gethdrrec LOOP
        -- Create JSON payload
            l_json.put('InvoiceNumber',i.document_id);
            l_json.put('InvoiceCurrency','USD');
            l_json.put('InvoiceAmount',i.amount);
            l_json.put('InvoiceDate', i.trx_date);
            l_json.put('BusinessUnit', 'ABCD Corp');
            l_json.put('Supplier', 'NASA');
            l_json.put('SupplierSite','PHYSICAL');
            l_json.put('InvoiceGroup','RR');
            l_json.put('Description', 'Some Descr');
            
            FOR j IN getlnrec(i.document_id) LOOP

              l_children.append(json_object_t('
             {  
                "LineNumber": "'|| j.line_id || '",
                "LineAmount": "'|| j.line_value|| '",
             }'));
              l_grandchild.append(json_object_t('
                { "DistributionLineNumber": "'|| j.line_id || '",
                  "DistributionLineType": "Item",
                  "DistributionAmount":"'|| j.line_value|| '",
                  "DistributionCombination": "254.000.000.2111010.000.0.0"
                 }'
                ));              
            END LOOP;
         
          END LOOP;

            l_json.put('invoiceLines', l_children);
            l_json.put('invoiceDistributions',l_grandchild);
            

        envelope := l_json.to_clob;
```

**Finally here is the example payload structure I am trying to generate using above methods**

```
{
    "InvoiceNumber": "MA_APInvoicex1",
    "InvoiceCurrency": "USD",
    "InvoiceAmount": 2212.75,
    "InvoiceDate": "2023-07-07",
    "BusinessUnit": "ABC Corp",
    "Supplier": "NASA",
    "SupplierSite": "Saint Paul",
    "InvoiceGroup": "July2023",
    "Description": "Office Supplies", 
    "invoiceLines": [{
        "LineNumber": 1,
        "LineAmount": 2112.75,
        "invoiceDistributions": [{
            "DistributionLineNumber": 1,
            "DistributionLineType": "Item",
            "DistributionAmount": 2112.75
        }]
        },
        {
            "LineNumber": 2,
            "LineType": "Freight",
            "LineAmount": 100,
            "ProrateAcrossAllItemsFlag": true,
            "invoiceDistributions": [{
                "DistributionLineNumber": 2,
                "DistributionLineType": "Item",
                "DistributionAmount": 2112.75
                 }]
        },{
            "LineNumber": 3,
            "LineType": "Freight",
            "LineAmount": 100,
            "ProrateAcrossAllItemsFlag": true,
            "invoiceDistributions": [{
                "DistributionLineNumber": 3,
                "DistributionLineType": "Item",
                "DistributionAmount": 2112.75
              }]
        }]
}
```

Here are tables to produce above query as requested by @MT0

```
CREATE TABLE xxrr_hdr_stg(document_id, amount, trx_date) AS
SELECT 543210, 100, SYSDATE FROM DUAL

CREATE TABLE xxrr_line_stg(document_id, line_id, line_value) AS
SELECT 543210, 1, 2112.75 FROM DUAL;

INSERT INTO  xxrr_line_stg(document_id, line_id, line_value) 
SELECT 543210, 2, 2112.75 FROM DUAL;

INSERT INTO  xxrr_line_stg(document_id, line_id, line_value) 
SELECT 543210, 3, 2112.75 FROM DUAL;

commit;
```

Please advise.

Thank you ,
Darsh

Comment: Maybe you should also post what you're getting now and why it is not what you want?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data; and the expected output for that sample data. If you do not tell us what data you are starting with and what you expect from that data and then say that the answers are not correct how do you expect a "correct" answer when we have no idea what that looks like.

Comment: Hello @MT0 I have edited my questions with to bring more clarity and table creation/insertion.

Answer (score 0):

That first option works fine but a nested object needs its own subquery. Here is an example on the emp/dept sample dataset. It selects from dual since the outer level is a single key that has the all rows in an array, but that can also be from a table like you're doing.

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT (
         KEY 'departments' VALUE (
           SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(
                    JSON_OBJECT (
                      KEY 'department_name' VALUE d.dname,
                      KEY 'department_no' VALUE d.deptno,
                      KEY 'employees' VALUE (
                        SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG (
                                 JSON_OBJECT(
                                   KEY 'employee_number' VALUE e.empno,
                                   KEY 'employee_name' VALUE e.ename
                                 )
                               )
                        FROM   emp e
                        WHERE  e.deptno = d.deptno
                      )
                    )
                  )
           FROM   dept d
         )
       ) AS departments
FROM   dual;

{
  "departments": [
    {
      "department_name": "ACCOUNTING",
      "department_no": 10,
      "employees": [
        {
          "employee_number": 7839,
          "employee_name": "KING"
        },
        {
          "employee_number": 7782,
          "employee_name": "CLARK"
        },
        {
          "employee_number": 7934,
          "employee_name": "MILLER"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "department_name": "RESEARCH",
      "department_no": 20,
      "employees": [
        {
          "employee_number": 7566,
          "employee_name": "JONES"
        },
        {
          "employee_number": 7788,
          "employee_name": "SCOTT"
        },
        {
          "employee_number": 7902,
          "employee_name": "FORD"
        },
        {
          "employee_number": 7369,
          "employee_name": "SMITH"
        },
        {
          "employee_number": 7876,
          "employee_name": "ADAMS"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "department_name": "SALES",
      "department_no": 30,
      "employees": [
        {
          "employee_number": 7698,
          "employee_name": "BLAKE"
        },
        {
          "employee_number": 7499,
          "employee_name": "ALLEN"
        },
        {
          "employee_number": 7521,
          "employee_name": "WARD"
        },
        {
          "employee_number": 7654,
          "employee_name": "MARTIN"
        },
        {
          "employee_number": 7844,
          "employee_name": "TURNER"
        },
        {
          "employee_number": 7900,
          "employee_name": "JAMES"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "department_name": "OPERATIONS",
      "department_no": 40,
      "employees": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: how can we achieve this using option 2, any advise?

Comment: You asked a very similar question 2 weeks ago - I would think that you can use the technique I described there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76957034/parsing-json-in-plsql

Comment: Note that option 1 will be a lot more performant. Only one sql statement is used.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `GROUP BY` clause when you have aggregated and non-aggregated columns. Given your structure you would want to use correlated sub-queries and `JSON_ARRAY` for the inner-most object (rather than `JSON_ARRAYAGG`, since you only have a single object and are not aggregating anything) :

```sql
SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
         KEY 'InvoiceNumber'   VALUE  h.document_id,
         KEY 'InvoiceCurrency' VALUE  'USD',
         KEY 'InvoiceAmount'   VALUE  h.amount,
         KEY 'InvoiceDate'     VALUE  h.trx_date,
         KEY 'BusinessUnit'    VALUE  'ABCD Corp',
         KEY 'Supplier'        VALUE  'NASA',
         KEY 'SupplierSite'    VALUE  'PHYSICAL',
         KEY 'InvoiceGroup'    VALUE  'MoonLander',
         KEY 'Description'     VALUE  'Some Description',
         KEY 'invoiceLines'    VALUE  (
           SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(
                    JSON_OBJECT(
                      KEY 'LineNumber' VALUE t.line_id,
                      KEY 'LineAmount' VALUE t.line_Value,
                      KEY 'invoiceDistributions' VALUE JSON_ARRAY(
                        JSON_OBJECT(
                          KEY 'DistributionLineNumber' VALUE t.line_id,
                          KEY 'DistributionLineType'   VALUE 'Item',
                          KEY 'DistributionAmount'     VALUE  t.line_Value
                        )
                      )
                    )
                  )
           FROM   XXRR_LINE_STG t
           WHERE  t.document_id = h.document_id
         )
       ) AS json_value
--INTO   aCLOB
FROM   XXRR_HDR_STG h
WHERE  h.document_id = 543210;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE xxrr_hdr_stg(document_id, amount, trx_date) AS
SELECT 543210, 100, SYSDATE FROM DUAL

CREATE TABLE xxrr_line_stg(document_id, line_id, line_value) AS
SELECT 543210, 1, 2112.75 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| JSON_VALUE |
| --- |
| {"InvoiceNumber":543210,"InvoiceCurrency":"USD","InvoiceAmount":100,"InvoiceDate":"2023-09-05T09:07:51","BusinessUnit":"ABCD Corp","Supplier":"NASA","SupplierSite":"PHYSICAL","InvoiceGroup":"MoonLander","Description":"Some Description","invoiceLines":[{"LineNumber":1,"LineAmount":2112.75,"invoiceDistributions":[{"DistributionLineNumber":1,"DistributionLineType":"Item","DistributionAmount":2112.75}]}]} |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xcq_u0He)

Comment: Issue with this is that if there are multiple rows then the HDR table information is repeating in the json output for each detail line.  I need to show HDR just once and then line.  there can be multiple line under one header, and multiple distributions under one line. something like this:

Header
......line1
.............distribution1
.............distribution2
......line2
..............distribution1
..............distribution2

Comment: @virtualtransfer [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77040975/edit) and provide a [MRE] that tells us the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data and what the expected output is for that sample data. (Do not use comments for posting data.)